# android clipboard broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, clipboard

I want to make a simple service, (which will run in the background) when any user copies anything from the browser or sms etc., there will be a toast showing that text

I have this code which gives toast when there is a phone call

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            // this code is for to accept the telephone call
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

and this code in manifest.xml

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
```

now this code tell to send any phone state to the `myreciever` class now I want to get text from clipboard manager. is there any `intent.action` state which can call `myreciever` class when someone copies text.

Any kind of help or code will be appreciated.

Comment: @lori would you help me how did you do that because i couldn't find

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since there is now Action intent for clipboard, what you will need to do is create a broadcast receiver to start when your app is started on when the device first boots up. And then start a service to monitor the state of the clipboard.

This is a PERFECT project on google code that will show you EXACTLY what to do.

[My Clip tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/my-clips/)

Comment: Dude you genious man thankx a lot...:D this exactly what i need

Comment: No problem =) Glad to have helped

Comment: Hi @coder_For_Life22 I couldnt checkout the code at the link u have given..could u share the link from wer i could dwnld the source

Comment: `my-clips` is too complicated.I do not understand what this project.please help me.**I need this** :( Please take a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with "coder_For_Life22":"*Since there is now Action intent for clipboard, ...*".
I found two ways for monitoring "clipboard":
1-A way like what says "coder_For_Life22".
2-Using "*ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener()*" method.
***But both of them have issues*** :
In first way if user copy a word for example "Text" and then (even after sometimes and in another App) again copy the same word,you can not detect it.
Second way, is a solution for using android 3.0 api 11 and not lower.